# Lowest varchar amount

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues comparing two values in the Mysql database and display the lowest one.

For instance I have this:

```
value1 = 23.4
value2 = 4.479
```

I tried this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(column AS SIGNED) ASC
```

but its not working

Again, field type is VARCHAR.

The result I am looking for should be 23.4 and not 4.479

any suggestions?

Comment: as wayne said, decimal is a better data type. You shouldn't store prices in varchar format

Comment: Am I missing something or you should be ordering DESC if you are looking for 23.4? I tried casting AS DECIMAL and it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Simply put, you need to change your column to DECIMAL if you're storing prices. VARCHAR will be in alphabetical order. Read up on [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) in MySQL.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN price DECIMAL(10,3);
```

Comment: unfortunately converting do decimal is not an option for me :(

Comment: I have to ask you: Why not?

Comment: the issue I am having is this....One number is coming in as 166 and the other one is coming in as 23.4. So, when I conver it to decimal the 166 will be 166.000 and 23.4 will be 234.000.

Comment: I set the decimal to DECIMAL(10,3)

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php to fix any display issues up :)

Comment: its not about display issue ;-). I need to get the lowest value from all the values I have in the price column. Any other advise. I searched online a lot and nothing seems to be working :(

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY MIN(price) LIMIT 1;

Comment: nope...doesn't work. When I convert it to Decimal it messes up the numbers in the DB and I don't get the right result

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: when I have the field type to decimal then I get 166.000 as the result. Since it is converting the number 166 to 166.000 and the 23.4 to 234.000....That's the issue what I have

Comment: 166 is the same as 166.000 though?

Comment: 166 is smaller than 234. But the original numbers are 166 and 23.4 You get my point?  ;-)

Comment: I do, but that sounds like a conversion issue that popped up when you were converting the data type of the column. Using a DECIMAL is a MUCH better solution than using a VARCHAR, even if it means having to reinsert some of the old data that existed before the conversion.

Comment: i see..thanks for your help though ;-)...i will post it here when I got the solution

Answer (score 0):

A pretty costly work-around for you is to cast all values to decimal before sorting:

`SELECT name, price FROM test ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(20, 10)) ASC LIMIT 1`

Just make sure your DECIMAL limits are enough to correctly cast all values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you CAST it to DECIMAL.

```
select * from tablename order by cast(price as decimal);

+--------+-------+
| name   | price |
+--------+-------+
| nail   | 0.95  |
| glue   | 9.23  |
| hammer | 45.12 |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: no luck. I am having these three values. 166, 23.4, 3.391 and it shows 3.391 as the lowest. Again, the field type is still VARCHAR

Comment: my goal here is to get 23.4 as the result

Comment: You've lost me: 3.391 is the lowest value. Perhaps you should state more clearly what you want to do. You state in your original post that you want to sort the numbers in ascending order numerically; using CAST work work to do that. If you want your values in another order, please specify what you want.